# ASP.NET site moved to new server. How do I redirect all page requests (including querystrings) to the same page on the new server?

Tags: asp.net, redirect

My company has moved an internal web site to a different server. I have been asked to do the following when someone uses a link to the old site location:

> Display a page that tells the user that the site has moved, display
>   the new url, and ask the user to update their bookmarks, then after 15
>   seconds, redirect them to the new page location, including the
>   querystring.

I've found example of using rewrites and redirects but it looks like they cover the entire server. I only want to redirect all pages for a single site on the server.

So i'm looking for how to redirect any request to a single site on an asp.net server to a "Please change your bookmark" page that will then forward them on to the same location on a different server.  Appreciate all suggestions.

Edit: Clarification. For a single asp.net application within an asp.net site.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out so I'll post it here for others to find.  In ASP.NET, I used a file called "app_offline.htm" and placed it in the root directory of the web application on the old server. Now when people hit any page in that app, they see the app_offline page.  The code looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This page has moved</title>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 style="text-align:center">This page has been moved to:<br /><br />
            <a href="test" id="aNewLoc"><span id="spanNewLoc"></span></a><br /><br />
            Please update any bookmarks you may have.<br /><br />
            You may click the link to go there now, or wait <span id="spanTimeout">15</span> seconds to be redirected automatically.
        </h2>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var timeout = 15;
        document.getElementById("aNewLoc").href = newLoc();
        document.getElementById("spanNewLoc").innerText = newLoc();
        setTimeout(countDown, 1000);

        function newLoc() {
            return 'http://newurl.com' + location.pathname + location.search;
        }

        function countDown() {
            timeout = timeout - 1;
            document.getElementById("spanTimeout").innerText = timeout;
            if (timeout == 0) {
                window.location.href = newLoc();
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
            }
        }

    </script>
</html>
```